# How to refactor logging statements in sibling classes?

Tags: java, logging

As system evolves, the logging statements will be changed to meet the new requirements, and ideally the logging statements which have identical or very similar context should be changed consistently. But in many cases it's hard for developers to remember the existence of all of them. Then they may only change a portion of them, and forget to change the other ones consistently.

Take this Java code snippet as an example, there are two sibling classes (ChildClassA, ChildClassB) which both extend the same superclass (ParentClass), and they have a pair of similar methods which have similar functions and contain the same logging statements.

```
public class ChildClassA implements ParentClass{
  public void processShellCommand(){
  ...
  logger.error("Error initializing command, field " + field.getName() + " is not accessible.");
  ...
 }

public class ChildClassB implements ParentClass{
  public void processNetworkCommand(){
  ...
  logger.error("Error initializing command, field " + field.getName() + " is not accessible.");
  ...
 }
```

Is there a solution such as a tool, or some documents, etc. that can help the consistent changing of them?

Comment: The general approach is called re-factoring. You might consider adding a method in the parent class that generates the error string for that case: `logger.error( notAccessible( field.getName() ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to logging I think you really should try to avoid putting details in the log.[whatever_leve].([message_text]] statement (at least when in comes to errors), instead you want to create your own Exception classes and put message details in them. Have a filter/interceptor for dealing with logging of unexpected exceptions is also a good practice.

So in you code example that would be that the sub-classes thrown a typed Exception, lets call it InitializingException(...). It is then up the the caller or a filter to deal with it and log it.

You want to care about the logging part of your code base in the same way as you do for business-logic code (one can argue it is part of it), so salute DRY (do-not-repeat-yourself).

Same logic applies for Debug and Trace statements as well, you don't want to copy-paste the same message across the system. So general refactoring should be applied to avoid it. But I generally think the a debug or trace message is likely to change (it is up to the developer).